# Is it possible that everything is fine when runnning on Tomcat server then something is wrong when the system is deployed on the internet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web

I have this system where there is a registration form. Once submitted, if there is some validations that did not pass when the user presses the back button on that page and returns to the register page, the values he inputted will still be on that page along with error messages in red. This works fine in Tomcat.

Now I have the same code and it is running on the internet now. When the validations fail and go to the page where there is a back button, when it is pressed all the values are gone from the registration page with no valdiation errors. Is this possible? What could have happened?

Regards,

J Roq

PS: This is the JSP code where I think it goes wrong, this is the code that will render the page with the  back button:

```
<c:if
        test="${!empty sessionScope.RegistrationForm.problamticCode}">
        <br><br></br><input type="button" value="BACK"
                    onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" />

    </c:if>

    <c:if
        test="${empty sessionScope.RegistrationForm.problamticCode}">
          <%request.getSession().removeAttribute("registrationFormObject"); %>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: ofcourse they will be gone unless the scope is session.

Comment: I used a session, gave it the registration form object which contains all values. It works in TOMCAT but in the internet somehow the object is lost when I press back.

Comment: What do you mean by 'works in TOMCAT but in the internet '? What is serving this to 'internet'?

Comment: Also you need to post the code can not just guess it.

Comment: I mean the system is now in production. Tomcat refers to my localhost. It works in my localhost but in production it doesn't work. What could be the problem? Okay will post code.

Comment: Maybe some users disabled cookies?

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge number of reasons why it might be behaving differently, including: Browser type, browser version, security settings.  And that's just on the client side: there are many server-side issues to consider, too.

SUGGESTION:

Try "formretain.js", from Dynamic Drive, and see if it fixes the problem:

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/formremember.htm

Also, this article has some great background:

- http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/backbuttonblues.html